# javascript manage shared resource access for asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, race-condition

I'm writing a node.js server script that uses a shared text list data for multiple clients asynchronously.

the clients can read, add or update items of this shared list.

```
static getitems(){
    if (list== undefined) list = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./list.json"));
    return list;
}

static additem(newitem){
    var key = Object.keys(newitem)[0];
    list[key] = newitem[key];
    fs.writeFileSync("./list.json", JSON.stringify(list));
}
```

clients can modify and get the list data using the following express APIs

```
app.get("/getlist"), (req, res)=>{
    res.send(TempMan.getTemplates());
});

app.post("/addlist"), (req, res)=>{
    additem(req.body.newitem)
    res.status(204).end()
});
```

with long background in C#, C++ and other desktop programming languages, although I red javascript doesn't run into race condition, I am so worried resource sharing is going to be a problem. I was first thinking of semaphores or shared lock or some other multiple thread management solutions in other languages, but yet read javascript doesn't need such methods.


does such node.js implementation run to resource sharing problem such as simultaneous attempts of file read/write? how can I solve this? do I need some kind of transaction functions I can use in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a Node.js program **may** encounter a resource sharing problem you call, usually, we call it "**race condition**" problems. It is not due to two threads/processes but it is due to the intrinsic property: **async**. Assume that there are two async functions, the first one has started but is not finished and it has some `await` inside, in this situation, the second async function can start. It may cause race conditions if they access the same resource in their code blocks.

I have made a slide to introduce this issue: https://slides.com/grimmer/intro_js_ts_task_queuelib_d4c/fullscreen#/0/12.

Go back to your example code, your code **WILL NOT** have any race conditions. Even you put any usage of async function inside express routing callback instead of `fs.writeFileSync`, the reason is that the implementation of Express will await the first async routing callback handler function and only starts to execute the second async routing callback handler function after the first one is finished.

For example:

```
app.post('/testing1', async (req, res) => {
  // Do something here
});

    
app.post('/testing2', async (req, res) => {
  // Do something here
});
```

is like the below code in the implementation of Express,

```
async function expressCore() {
  await 1st_routing_call_back()
  await 2nd_routing_call_back()     
}
```

But please keep in mind that the other server frameworks may not have the same behavior. https://www.apollographql.com/ and https://nestjs.com/ both allow two async routing methods to be executed concurrently. Like below

```
async function otherServerFrameworkCore() {
  1st_routing_call_back()
  2nd_routing_call_back()     
}
```

and you need to find a way to avoid race conditions if this is your concern. Either using transaction for DB usage or some npm synchronization libraries which are lightweight and suitable for single Node.js instance program, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/d4c-queue which is made by me. Multi Node.js instances are multi-processes and should have possible race condition issues and DB transaction is a more suitable solution.